# How do I print the result of a search() method in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, methods, return, document.write

I posted a question earlier regarding a school problem I was working on. I have what I believe to be the correct function per the assignment, but I am stuck. I need to have the alert() in my code display the index position of the substring it is searching for. Everything else works but I don't know how to send that info back to a variable that I can print to the screen. My code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Lesson 6 Application Project A</title>

<script language="JavaScript" type=text/javascript>
<!--
    /***************************************************************************** 
    The placeholders sub and string are used to pass as arguments the 
    user's entry into the text box and the textarea.  The variable where 
    is assigned the result of a method which returns the index (integer) 
    of the first occurence of sub (the string the program is searching for).
    Start the search at the beginning of string (the text that is being searched).
    Since the string is zero based, add 1 is to get the correct position of sub.
    *****************************************************************************/

    function search(sub, string) {
        var where;

        if (string.search(sub) != -1){
            where = alert("Your index position is: " + where);
        }
        else{
            where = alert("Could not find your string!");
        } 




    }
//-->
</script>
</head>

<body>

<h3>CIW JavaScript Specialist</h3>
<hr />

<form name="myForm">
<p>
<strong>Look for:</strong>
<input type="text" name="what" size="20" />
</p>

<p>
<strong>in this string:</strong>
<textarea name="toSearch" rows="4" cols="30" wrap="virtual">
</textarea>
</p>

<p>
<input type="button" value="Search"
onclick="search(myForm.what.value, myForm.toSearch.value);" />
</p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `alert` returns nothing and `where` is undefined when you use it in `alert`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function search(sub, string) {
    var where = string.indexOf(sub);

    if (where != -1){
        alert("Your index position is: " + where);
    }
    else{
        alert("Could not find your string!");
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your where variable should be assinged to the result of the search.

```
function search(sub, string) {
        var where = string.search(sub);

        if (where != -1){
            alert("Your index position is: " + (where + 1));
        }
        else{
            alert("Could not find your string!");
        } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

My solution to my own problem was to create a variable called position and set it to receive the index position of the substring. I could then add that into my alert() and display the results to the screen. Corrected code is as follows:

```
function search(sub, string) {
        var where;
        var position = string.search(sub);

        if (string.search(sub) != -1){
            where = alert("Your index position is: " + position);
        }
        else{
            where = alert("Could not find your string!");
        } 




    }
```

Comment: What's the point of `where`? And why not `if (position != -1)`?

Comment: I frequently run into the problem of doing more work than i need to.  I saw where I went wrong and have committed that to memory. Thanks for all the quick responses.